# Where does the downloaded models in JupyterNotebook locat at?

Tags: python, pip, nlp, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

[image]

When I run this command, I can see that I download the model. So, where are these kind of downloaded model/data/tokenizers stored in my machine ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

From [this GitHub page](https://github.com/LuoweiZhou/pytorch-pretrained-BERT#loading-google-ai-or-openai-pre-trained-weights-or-pytorch-dump):

> ...the pre-trained weights will be downloaded from AWS S3 ... and stored in a cache folder to avoid future download (the cache folder can be found at `~/.pytorch_pretrained_bert/`).

So the default directory is `~/.pytorch_pretrained_bert/`.

You can download the weights to any other directory with the `cache_dir` argument to `from_pretrained`:

> `cache_dir` can be an optional path to a specific directory to download and cache the pre-trained model weights

Comment: I am using Conda, So do I expect to find this model under Conda or the path under JupyterNotebook?

Comment: @JustinZackerbug, the `~` in the path is your home directory. It doesn't depend on Conda or Jupyter

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for models downloaded by jupyterNotebook on WINDOWS then you can see in following path:-

[Here is image CLICK ON IT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Msqt.jpg)

```
C:\Users\<yourUserName>\.cache

C:\Users\<yourUserName>\.cache\torch
```

Example in my case it was:

```
C:\Users\adity\.cache\torch\
```